# "GoogleApiClient is not connected yet" on logout when using Firebase auth with google sign in

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm using Firebase auth with Google Sign In but I want to signout from another activity but when I logout using this method which works perfectly from the same activity but not with another activity. Here is the method.

```
public void logOut() {
        mAuth.signOut();
        // Google sign out
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(googleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                        authorizeUser(null);
                    }
                });
    }
```

But when making this method static and the googleApiClient static it still doesn't work and when i perform only

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

the error i m getting is this (logcat)

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process: com.igov, PID: 21316
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoe.zzd(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoh.zzd(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzof.zzd(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzc.signOut(Unknown Source)
      at com.igov.design.LoginActivity.logOut(LoginActivity.java:159)
      at com.igov.design.LoginActivity$2.onClick(LoginActivity.java:62)
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
      at com.igov.design.MainActivity.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:101)
      at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:152)
      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:810)
      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:957)
      at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:318)
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: The exception is quite explicit: you're trying to use GoogleApiClient when it isn't initialized yet. Did you try any of the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=GoogleApiClient+is+not+connected+yet ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Register a Connection Callback to Google Api Client**

**Classes Used:**

- LoginActivity class (Activity to Login)
- LogoutActivity class (Activity to Logout)

**Code:**

```
    public void logout() {
       mGoogleApiClient.connect();
       mGoogleApiClient.registerConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                        if (status.isSuccess()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "User Logged out");
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LogoutActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Google API Client Connection Suspended");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: if you still facing issue , feel free to comment.

Comment: hey i tried your code.. i got null pointer exception in this line:  mGoogleApiClient.connect();

Comment: I think you need to add also unregisterConnectionCallbacks after your flow is finished.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the login using google and logout from different activity and facing this error especially on logout then please check this line if you found it in your code then remove it.

```
                                mGoogleApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
/*this line should be removed*/.enableAutoManage(this , this)
                               .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                               .build()
```